# String formatting keeps printing out the same argument

Tags: python, format

I hope that no one takes it the wrong way, but I find the str.format() documentation in Python to be too theoretical, and impractical.

Junk like keyword arguments (seriously?) is strewn all over the place, but the simplest use case of formatted variable output, using fixed width, which is so beautifully and succinctly defined in Fortran 95, or C++, is not shown in any of the examples I can find online. I have got nothing against keywords, but at least describe how to do less fancy and more common tasks so that a newbie like me does not have to guess what is wrong with syntax.

I have some numbers I need to output in a table. These are results of calculations, whatever. Can someone tell me why the following code simply replicates ft1 all over the place?

```
print("\tFull Time\tPart Time\tNew Hires\nInsured\t{0:<8d}\t{0:<8d}\t{0:<8d}\nUninsured\t{0:<8d}\t{0:<8d}\t{0:<8d}\n\n\nNumber of employees with lapsed insurance\t{0:<8d}\nNumber of employees with COBRA coverage\t{0:<8d}".format(ft1,pt1,nh1,uft1,upt1,unh1,lapsed1,cobra1))
```

All the variables above are integers. I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: when you put a `{0:}` it will print the argument at index 0, which is `ft1`. just remove it everywhere and the elements will appear in order. just keep `{:<8d}`

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. Can you submit that as an answer so that I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: That's very kind of you to think of that. I added it as an answer. If you feel like I should add anything please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `str.format()` with an index, like `{0}`, the item that will be printed inside is the one at the corresponding index of the supplied arguments. Since you wrote `{0}` multiple times, only the first argument will be printed. For instance:

```
print('First: {0}\nFirst again: {0}\nFirst one more time: {0}'.format(
    'word1', 'word2', 'word3'))
```

```
First: word1
First again: word1
First one more time: word1
```

Since you have only a few arguments, and you don't seem to want to reuse them multiple times, you can just omit the zero and use this `{}` and the arguments will be place in order.

```
print('First: {}\nSecond: {}\nThird: {}'.format('word1', 'word2', 'word3'))
```

or

```
print('First: {0}\nSecond: {1}\nThird: {2}'.format('word1', 'word2', 'word3'))
```

```
First: word1
Second: word2
Third: word3
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use f-strings? When working with many variables in a string it could make it more readable and easier to debug wrong or missing values.

```py
print(f"\tFull Time\tPart Time\tNew Hires\nInsured\t{ft1:<8d}\t{pt1:<8d}\t{nh1:<8d}\nUninsured\t{uft1:<8d}\t{upt1:<8d}\t{unh1:<8d}\n\n\nNumber of employees with lapsed insurance\t{lapsed1:<8d}\nNumber of employees with COBRA coverage\t{cobra1:<8d}")
```

Comment: this is not an answer. it's an opinion

Comment: Yes but it might still help the OP to get the right result.

Comment: it doesn't. it doesn't solve OP's current problem, and brings an opinionated answer (which is inappropriate for this site). please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It is simply a suggestion when working with that many variables in a string it could make his life easier.

Comment: Thanks. I think that f-strings are messy and fail the first test (at least for me) as they do not separate out the format from the data. If you see, the names of variables are mixed in with the format string. I would not want to do that in a million years. YMMV, but this type of mess should not exist in any language.